# How to apply the returned values to multiple selectors in several different places

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function `calculate_discount(subTotal)` returns various values in the form of a Javascript object.

```
return {
    subTotal: subTotal, 
    subTotalFixed: subTotalFixed,
    discount_percent: discount,
    discount: discount, 
    net_discount: net_discount,
    net_discountFixed: net_discountFixed,
    gst: gst,
    final_total: final_total,
    finalTotalFixed: finalTotalFixed
};
```

So, when I want to make use of this function, I recover the values like so:

```
var calculations = newCalculate(subTotal);
var subTotalFixed =   calculations.subTotalFixed;                     
var discount_percent =  calculations.discount_percent;                
var discount = calculations.discount;
var discountFixed = calculations.discount;
var gst = calculations.gst;
var net_discount = calculations.net_discount;
var net_discountFixed = calculations.net_discountFixed;
var finalTotalFixed = calculations.finalTotalFixed;
var final_total = calculations.final_total;

$("#subtotal_hidden").val(subTotal);                                          //THIS IS TO ALLOW THE PASSING OF AN UNFORMATED VALUE IN THE POST ARRAY THAT LARAVEL PICKS UP.
$("#subtotal").val(subTotalFixed);
$("#discount_hidden").val(discount_percent);
$("#discount_value").val(discountFixed);
$("#discount_value_hidden").val(discount);
$("#gst").val(gst);
$("#gst_hidden").val(gst);
$("#net_discount").val(net_discountFixed);
$("#net_discount_hidden").val(net_discount);
$("#final_total").val(finalTotalFixed);
$("#final_total_hidden").val(final_total);
```

This all works great, however, I want to output the exact same values in multiple places, using the exact same selectors. I do not want to repeat the above code and the selectors every time I want to use it. So how can I store this ONCE and call it when I need it ? tks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to output the exact same values in multiple places using the same selectors"?

Comment: Why don't you move this code to the separate funtion? some thing like setValues(values, $form)? You can modify your selectors to search inside the particular parent element using find() function. Something like this: $form.find("#subtotal_hidden").val(values.subTotal);

Comment: Create a function that allows you to pass in values and write those values to the elements.  This will prevent you from having to rewrite the code

Comment: @RayfenWindspear what I mean is the values need to be output in different places on the same HTML page, or on different HTML pages, or they might be output by different events being fired.  tks

Comment: Then @PavelPykhtin has the solution you probably want.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear If I were to use the same selector on two different pages, will there be a conflict between them or is JS smart enough to know that they come from different locations? tks

Comment: @Vince That is the beauty of the .find function. It starts the search at whatever element it is being called on. Wrap all the ones you are changing in some div with an ID, say "update-values", then when you call $('#update-values').find(), the jQuery search ignores the rest of the page and searches ONLY the children of that div. Then you could differentiate between them in different locations with some naming system in the IDs e.g. update-values1, update-values2...

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Ok, understood. However each div would need it's distinct ID to avoid conflict correct ? tks

Comment: @Vince Right. I'm not sure how permissive HTML is with IDs, if it whines and gives you problems, simply switch to classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function like this to set values:

```
function setValues(values, $form){
    $form.find("#subtotal_hidden").val(values.subTotal);
    $form.find("#subtotal").val(values.subTotalFixed);
    $form.find("#discount_hidden").val(values.discount_percent);
    $form.find("#discount_value").val(values.discountFixed);
    $form.find("#discount_value_hidden").val(values.discount);
    $form.find("#gst").val(values.gst);
    $form.find("#gst_hidden").val(values.gst);
    $form.find("#net_discount").val(values.net_discountFixed);
    $form.find("#net_discount_hidden").val(values.net_discount);
    $form.find("#final_total").val(values.finalTotalFixed);
    $form.find("#final_total_hidden").val(values.final_total);
}
```

And call it this way:

```
var calculations = newCalculate(subTotal);
setValues(calculations, $(document));

setValues(calculations, $('#my-form'));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! tks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a structure that is available at the appropriate scope. You can create a property that is loaded the first time you call the method. You can use the property later on.

```
var discountCalcs = {
    'discounts': null, 
    'calculate_discount': function(subTotal) {      
        if (this.discounts == null) {
            //perform calculation logic

            this.discounts = {
                subTotal: subTotal, 
                subTotalFixed: subTotalFixed,
                discount_percent: discount,
                discount: discount, 
                net_discount: net_discount,
                net_discountFixed: net_discountFixed,
                gst: gst,
                final_total: final_total,
                finalTotalFixed: finalTotalFixed
            };
        }

        return this.discounts;
    }
};

//first time
var discounts = discountCalcs.calculate_discount(12.34);

//subsequent times
var discounts2 = discountCalcs.discounts;
//or, this would produce the same value as the above line
var discounts3 = discountCalcs.calculate_discount();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 with jQuery.

```js
$(function () {
  showTotals();
});
        
function showTotals() {
  // replace for your calculation method
  var calculations = {
    subTotal: 10, 
    subTotalFixed: 10.50,
    discount_percent: 0.50
  };

  $(".totals").each( function() {
    var type = $(this).data("type");
    
    if(type !== "" && typeof type !== "undefined")
      $( this ).val( calculations[type] );
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="totals" data-type="subTotal"/>
<input type="text" class="totals" data-type="subTotalFixed"/>
<input type="text" class="totals" data-type="discount_percent"/>
```